# Преобразование строки к виду 1994-02-01

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка `01.02.1994`.
Нужно получить строку в виде `1994-02-01`.

Есть ли способ так сделать? Какие методы использовать для строк?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'01.02.1994'.split('.').reverse().join('-')
```

разбиваем на части по точкам, переворачиваем задом наперед, собираем обратно через тире.

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log('01.02.1994'.replace(/^(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$/, '$3-$2-$1'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
console.log(formatDate(new Date('01.02.1994')));
```

Comment: Со строкой из вопроса ваша функция не работает

Comment: Надо new Date добавить.

Comment: Ноликов нет: `1994-1-2`, а просили `1994-02-01`.

Comment: А результат `new Date('01.02.1994')`, часом, не будет зависеть от локали?

Comment: `2017-7-18` и `NaN-NaN-NaN`. Почему этот ответ принят лол?)

Answer (score 2):

Странно, что нет варианта с [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) и регулярками

```js
console.log(
'01.02.1994'.replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/,'$3-$2-$1')
);
```

Comment: Опоздали, Qwertiy уже написал :)

Comment: Кто-то минусует регулярки :(

Comment: @Qwertiy [Вполне заслуженно](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split-reverse-join/1)

Comment: А чего мою не проверил. И вариант с датой валится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Обновил -  https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-split-reverse-join.