# Как преобразовать строку к виду 1/2/1994?

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать строку 01.02.1994 к виду 1/2/1994 js

Comment: такой вид жестко задан? или могут быть варианты?

Comment: у меня дата рождения вводится в виде 01.02.1994
нужно узнать возраст . делаю так как тут https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee532932(v=vs.94).aspx

или нужно перевести в миллисекунды введенное значение 01.02.1994

Comment: ну тогда боюсь вы изначально не корректно задали вопрос, спросили вообще не то, что надо на самом деле. но ответ на заданный вопрос уже дали ...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование строки к виду 1994-02-01](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693557/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83-1994-02-01)

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log('01.02.1994'.split('.').map(num => +num).join('/'));
```

Comment: Можно `.map(Number)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log("01.02.1994".replace(/^0?(\d+)\.0?(\d+)\.(\d+)$/, '$1/$2/$3'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если разговор идет о строке то можно применить такой вариант:

```js
var str = "1.2.1994";
var newStr = str.replace(/\./g, '/');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: В вопросе ещё нули убираться должны. И не надо удалять ответы и писать такие же.